# windows security non admin user and command prompt

Tags: windows, security

We have a local network with several windows clients and a few windows server. for security purpose, almost all users account set as not admin on their machines.
our network security admin claim that they must restrict to command prompt because some users may use cmd ( while they are not admin ) and access to more resources that they are not permitted.

in other side some of our users need cmd for their jobs sometimes. 
now we have to decide , can we keep cmd available for our users or it make a potential risk for our system that we can't ignore it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to follow some guidance. When hardening an operating system thousands of configuration items an be customised in many different ways. A good place to start is with the CIS (Center for Internet Security) guidance. The CIS publishes security benchmarks for most common operating systems and applications. You can download the benchmarks here: https://learn.cisecurity.org/benchmarks

In respect of your original question, I've quickly skimmed the Windows 7 CIS Benchmark doc and it doesn't seem to mention locking down the command prompt or PowerShell. That said, I also checked the CESG guidance (UK Government IT Security Guidelines) and they suggest using AppLocker to prevent user access to CMD.exe. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/end-user-devices-security-guidance-windows-7/end-user-devices-security-guidance-windows-7

TLDR: Security is difficult, and the level of 'lock down' you place upon your users is going to be different from the level I apply against mine. If your users don't need access to cmd prompt, don't give it to them. Before you remove it though consider whether or not you need to retain CMD.exe for troubleshooting end user problems (running in the logged on users' context).

Answer (score 0):

In 99% of all companies giving employees only user accounts (and not admin accounts) is enough.

Don't start to try removing system tool like cmd, or locking the control panel or removing access to the C-Drive or any funny solutions.

So no, do not remove access to the command line. It's a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is 99% of companies have bad security.

Cmd.exe can be removed through the group policy setting "Prevent access to the command prompt." It's under User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\System.

If you enable that setting in a GPO linked at the domain level, for example, you could use a security filter to give the desired users access to cmd.exe.